# GHunt error for check_and_gen.py'

Tags: python, kali-linux

while installing GHunt on Kali Linux with Python version 3.9, check_and_gen.py file is not generating.

Following error:

```
python3: can't open file '/home/kali/GHunt/check_and_gen.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Following are the folder details:

```
cd GHunt
assets  examples  ghunt  LICENSE.md  main.py  README.md  requirements.txt  setup.py
cd ghunt
apis  cli.py  config.py  errors.py  ghunt.py  globals.py  helpers  __init__.py  knowledge  modules  objects  parsers  protos
```

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?